# How do I do select specific rows in a table based on specific conditions in the table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have sat all day thinking about this problem and I can't seem to come up with a solution. Lets make an example, I have a table that looks like this:

```
| movies | personname  | personrole |  
-------------------------------------
| A      | p1          | director   |  
| A      | p1          | producer   |  
| A      | p1          | writer     |
| A      | p1          | actor      |
| A      | p2          | actor      |  
| A      | p3          | writer     |
| A      | p3          | producer   |
| B      | p4          | director   |
| B      | p4          | producer   |
| B      | p4          | writer     |
```

Now, what I want to do is to list all people in this table that *was a director, producer, and a writer for a movie*. Any help is appreciated!

```
This as output: 

| movies | personname | 
-----------------------
| A      | p1         | 
| B      | p4         |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is called [SQL of Relational Division](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/).

```
SELECT  movies,
        personName
FROM    tableName
WHERE   personrole IN ('director','producer','writer')
GROUP   BY movies, personName
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 3
```

if `personrole` is not unique for every `movies`, and `personname`, you need to count unique values using `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT  movies,
        personName
FROM    tableName
WHERE   personrole IN ('director','producer','writer')
GROUP   BY movies, personName
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT personrole) = 3
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*both queries*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97136/1)

Comment: Didn't know the problem had a name, but thanks a ton! this works great!